# How can I provide access of a class from one file only to another class in another file (sort of like friend class functionality)

Tags: ios, swift, friend, access-control

Say I have 2 class types: `DataObject`, and `DataObjectManager`, and they each have their own swift files to keep things neat and clean.

The `DataObjectManager` does what the name implies: it manages `DataObject`s. The `DataObjectManager` is a singleton, and it owns instances of `DataObject`, particularly an `activeDataObject`, which is the getter that the rest of the project uses to get the `DataObject` that holds the data they need.

I don't want the other modules of code in my project to be able to change the properties of the `activeDataObject`, so I've defined almost all of it's properties with the `private(set)` access control. This keeps the rest of the code from being able to modify the properties of a `DataObject`. But this also keep the `DataObjectManager` from being able to modify them. Additionally, I only want the `DataObjectManager` to be able to create `DataObject` instances, but I can't declare the `init` as private because the `DataObjectManager` is in a different file.

I know of one solution, which would be to move all of the `DataObject` class code into the top (or bottom) of the `DataObjectManager`'s class file, but I have them in separate files not for functionality, but for tidiness.

Is there any way to keep my separate-file-tidiness and still get the access control I'm looking for? Or is my only option to just throw the `DataObject` class into the `DataObjectManager`'s class file (or class directly), and mark all of the properties as `private(set)` and the `init` as `private`?

**Edit**: See this radar to understand sort of what I mean. http://www.openradar.appspot.com/17136480

Answer (score 2):

You currently only have three options for access modifiers in Swift.

- `internal` - this is the default state. It means you can access the class/function/property in any other file in the same target.
- `private` - as you know, this restricts access to only the current file.
- `public` - this allows access from any file in any target.

If you can't do what you need with those three rules, then you can't do it.

So you have to decide which is "messier" - having both classes in the same source file (which, assuming only your `DataObjectManager` is actually used outside the file, seems acceptable), or keeping the `init` method and properties `internal`.

Source: [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)